# How to download SAS(Shared Acess signature) of an Azure File share onto Linux machine

Tags: linux, azure, azure-storage, fileshare, azure-cli

I have a SAS generated for a file share(with read and list privileges(no write privileges). 
my SAS looks like the following format : 
“https://test.file.core.windows.net/testf1?[some_token_here]
. I used Azcopy to download the files through above SAS onto a windows virtual machine however Azcopy is not present in Linux.

How do I download the files using the above SAS onto my linux virtual machine(I run ubuntu 14.04 but i prefer a answer that runs on most linux distros)? I'd prefer using a single line of code to carry out the above task. I tried working with Azure-cli but I was unable to find any success.

ps: I am very new to Azure

Comment: What did you try with azure-cli?

Comment: I tried   'azure storage share download "source" "dest" ' and also 'azure storage file copy' command. Not very sure how to go about it because l am not proficient with azure cli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the latest Azure-Cli, you might want to try:

`azure storage file upload [options] [source] [share] [path]`

`azure storage file download [options] [share] [path] [destination]`

Please try `azure storage file` for more help information.